# ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction in Scale Grid

Tags: postgresql

I have micro services developed in Java and node JS technologies. These services are connecting postgres for DB in Scale Grid.

Sometimes the services connects to read-only secondary server for no reason an gets below error for few seconds, after that it works normally

`ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction`

BTW, DB servers are hosted in Scale Grid.

Is there anyway that set a property so the  services can wait till it gets connection from primary ?

Any other solutions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: use [`target_session_attrs`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-TARGET-SESSION-ATTRS) in your libpq connection string. The values `primary` (or, since this is not available with older releases) `read-write` will only accept connections to the primary server.